# awk to re-arrange rows in execution data log

Tags: bash, awk

I've got a log file named kmeans_fastflow.log that looks like this:

```
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 1    execution_time_in_seconds: 8.001152 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 1    execution_time_in_seconds: 7.981428 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 1    execution_time_in_seconds: 7.986656 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 1    execution_time_in_seconds: 7.979782 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 1    execution_time_in_seconds: 7.980070 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 1    execution_time_in_seconds: 7.987722 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 1    execution_time_in_seconds: 7.980716 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 1    execution_time_in_seconds: 7.980209 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 1    execution_time_in_seconds: 7.982284 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 1    execution_time_in_seconds: 7.979446 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 2    execution_time_in_seconds: 4.003821 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 2    execution_time_in_seconds: 4.003638 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 2    execution_time_in_seconds: 4.003149 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 2    execution_time_in_seconds: 4.005415 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 2    execution_time_in_seconds: 4.003460 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 2    execution_time_in_seconds: 4.002836 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 2    execution_time_in_seconds: 4.005717 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 2    execution_time_in_seconds: 4.006178 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 2    execution_time_in_seconds: 4.004005 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 2    execution_time_in_seconds: 4.004230 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 3    execution_time_in_seconds: 2.673844 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 3    execution_time_in_seconds: 2.673601 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 3    execution_time_in_seconds: 2.675926 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 3    execution_time_in_seconds: 2.674989 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 3    execution_time_in_seconds: 2.673274 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 3    execution_time_in_seconds: 2.677280 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 3    execution_time_in_seconds: 2.676808 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 3    execution_time_in_seconds: 2.673376 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 3    execution_time_in_seconds: 2.672576 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 3    execution_time_in_seconds: 2.673550 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 4    execution_time_in_seconds: 2.008327 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 4    execution_time_in_seconds: 2.007571 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 4    execution_time_in_seconds: 2.007797 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 4    execution_time_in_seconds: 2.007576 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 4    execution_time_in_seconds: 2.010466 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 4    execution_time_in_seconds: 2.008056 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 4    execution_time_in_seconds: 2.007402 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 4    execution_time_in_seconds: 2.006869 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 4    execution_time_in_seconds: 2.006896 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 4    execution_time_in_seconds: 2.007455 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 5    execution_time_in_seconds: 1.608951 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 5    execution_time_in_seconds: 1.609970 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 5    execution_time_in_seconds: 1.608875 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 5    execution_time_in_seconds: 1.608379 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 5    execution_time_in_seconds: 1.608383 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 5    execution_time_in_seconds: 1.608388 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 5    execution_time_in_seconds: 1.607613 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 5    execution_time_in_seconds: 1.608727 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 5    execution_time_in_seconds: 1.609643 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 5    execution_time_in_seconds: 1.610055 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 6    execution_time_in_seconds: 1.343102 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 6    execution_time_in_seconds: 1.342790 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 6    execution_time_in_seconds: 1.347415 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 6    execution_time_in_seconds: 1.342613 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 6    execution_time_in_seconds: 1.343710 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 6    execution_time_in_seconds: 1.343529 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 6    execution_time_in_seconds: 1.345136 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 6    execution_time_in_seconds: 1.343854 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 6    execution_time_in_seconds: 1.342421 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 6    execution_time_in_seconds: 1.343624 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 7    execution_time_in_seconds: 1.153126 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 7    execution_time_in_seconds: 1.153022 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 7    execution_time_in_seconds: 1.152828 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 7    execution_time_in_seconds: 1.154386 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 7    execution_time_in_seconds: 1.152602 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 7    execution_time_in_seconds: 1.152872 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 7    execution_time_in_seconds: 1.153024 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 7    execution_time_in_seconds: 1.154684 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 7    execution_time_in_seconds: 1.153598 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 7    execution_time_in_seconds: 1.153146 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 8    execution_time_in_seconds: 1.011499 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 8    execution_time_in_seconds: 1.012181 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 8    execution_time_in_seconds: 1.011727 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 8    execution_time_in_seconds: 1.012070 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 8    execution_time_in_seconds: 1.011569 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 8    execution_time_in_seconds: 1.009917 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 8    execution_time_in_seconds: 1.011749 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 8    execution_time_in_seconds: 1.010674 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 8    execution_time_in_seconds: 1.010277 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 8    execution_time_in_seconds: 1.010382 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 9    execution_time_in_seconds: 0.899709 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 9    execution_time_in_seconds: 0.900500 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 9    execution_time_in_seconds: 0.900231 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 9    execution_time_in_seconds: 0.899769 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 9    execution_time_in_seconds: 0.899652 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 9    execution_time_in_seconds: 0.900219 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 9    execution_time_in_seconds: 0.900431 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 9    execution_time_in_seconds: 0.899219 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 9    execution_time_in_seconds: 0.899579 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 9    execution_time_in_seconds: 0.899830 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 10   execution_time_in_seconds: 0.811642 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 10   execution_time_in_seconds: 0.811074 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 10   execution_time_in_seconds: 0.812207 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 10   execution_time_in_seconds: 0.810524 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 10   execution_time_in_seconds: 0.812218 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 10   execution_time_in_seconds: 0.811673 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 10   execution_time_in_seconds: 0.810863 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 10   execution_time_in_seconds: 0.812428 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 10   execution_time_in_seconds: 0.811251 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 10   execution_time_in_seconds: 0.810584 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 11   execution_time_in_seconds: 0.738681 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 11   execution_time_in_seconds: 0.739885 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 11   execution_time_in_seconds: 0.740058 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 11   execution_time_in_seconds: 0.739330 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 11   execution_time_in_seconds: 0.739168 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 11   execution_time_in_seconds: 0.739263 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 11   execution_time_in_seconds: 0.739292 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 11   execution_time_in_seconds: 0.738528 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 11   execution_time_in_seconds: 0.739389 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 11   execution_time_in_seconds: 0.739759 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 12   execution_time_in_seconds: 0.679359 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 12   execution_time_in_seconds: 0.678121 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 12   execution_time_in_seconds: 0.680982 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 12   execution_time_in_seconds: 0.682098 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 12   execution_time_in_seconds: 0.679681 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 12   execution_time_in_seconds: 0.678525 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 12   execution_time_in_seconds: 0.679727 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 12   execution_time_in_seconds: 0.679983 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 12   execution_time_in_seconds: 0.678458 
data_set: data_set_1.txt        number_of_threads: 12   execution_time_in_seconds: 0.678074 
data_set: data_set_2.txt        number_of_threads: 1    execution_time_in_seconds: 56.425779    
data_set: data_set_2.txt        number_of_threads: 1    execution_time_in_seconds: 56.417835    
data_set: data_set_2.txt        number_of_threads: 1    execution_time_in_seconds: 56.426430    
data_set: data_set_2.txt        number_of_threads: 1    execution_time_in_seconds: 56.500974    
data_set: data_set_2.txt        number_of_threads: 1    execution_time_in_seconds: 56.447586    
data_set: data_set_2.txt        number_of_threads: 1    execution_time_in_seconds: 56.411380    
data_set: data_set_2.txt        number_of_threads: 1    execution_time_in_seconds: 56.453845    
data_set: data_set_2.txt        number_of_threads: 1    execution_time_in_seconds: 56.480448    
data_set: data_set_2.txt        number_of_threads: 1    execution_time_in_seconds: 56.442289    
data_set: data_set_2.txt        number_of_threads: 1    execution_time_in_seconds: 56.394068
.
.
.
data_set: data_set_2.txt        number_of_threads: 12   execution_time_in_seconds: 4.772698 
data_set: data_set_2.txt        number_of_threads: 12   execution_time_in_seconds: 4.761998 
data_set: data_set_2.txt        number_of_threads: 12   execution_time_in_seconds: 4.743285 
data_set: data_set_2.txt        number_of_threads: 12   execution_time_in_seconds: 4.746927 
data_set: data_set_2.txt        number_of_threads: 12   execution_time_in_seconds: 4.746411 
data_set: data_set_2.txt        number_of_threads: 12   execution_time_in_seconds: 4.758229 
data_set: data_set_2.txt        number_of_threads: 12   execution_time_in_seconds: 4.772117 
data_set: data_set_2.txt        number_of_threads: 12   execution_time_in_seconds: 4.767569 
data_set: data_set_2.txt        number_of_threads: 12   execution_time_in_seconds: 4.759577 
data_set: data_set_2.txt        number_of_threads: 12   execution_time_in_seconds: 4.753897 
data_set: data_set_3.txt        number_of_threads: 1    execution_time_in_seconds: 89.251694    
data_set: data_set_3.txt        number_of_threads: 1    execution_time_in_seconds: 89.348788    
data_set: data_set_3.txt        number_of_threads: 1    execution_time_in_seconds: 89.281708    
data_set: data_set_3.txt        number_of_threads: 1    execution_time_in_seconds: 89.278013    
data_set: data_set_3.txt        number_of_threads: 1    execution_time_in_seconds: 89.299754    
data_set: data_set_3.txt        number_of_threads: 1    execution_time_in_seconds: 89.443212    
data_set: data_set_3.txt        number_of_threads: 1    execution_time_in_seconds: 89.300965    
data_set: data_set_3.txt        number_of_threads: 1    execution_time_in_seconds: 89.374555    
data_set: data_set_3.txt        number_of_threads: 1    execution_time_in_seconds: 89.307755    
data_set: data_set_3.txt        number_of_threads: 1    execution_time_in_seconds: 89.342808
.
.
.
data_set: data_set_3.txt        number_of_threads: 12   execution_time_in_seconds: 7.533035 
data_set: data_set_3.txt        number_of_threads: 12   execution_time_in_seconds: 7.556848 
data_set: data_set_3.txt        number_of_threads: 12   execution_time_in_seconds: 7.558419 
data_set: data_set_3.txt        number_of_threads: 12   execution_time_in_seconds: 7.557569 
data_set: data_set_3.txt        number_of_threads: 12   execution_time_in_seconds: 7.533890 
data_set: data_set_3.txt        number_of_threads: 12   execution_time_in_seconds: 7.565937 
data_set: data_set_3.txt        number_of_threads: 12   execution_time_in_seconds: 7.579489 
data_set: data_set_3.txt        number_of_threads: 12   execution_time_in_seconds: 7.546736 
data_set: data_set_3.txt        number_of_threads: 12   execution_time_in_seconds: 7.539902 
data_set: data_set_3.txt        number_of_threads: 12   execution_time_in_seconds: 7.552226
```

As we can see, the number_of_threads varies from 1 to 12, there are 10 executions for each and these data are sorted by dataset, which can be data_set_1, data_set_2 and data_set_3. Desired output is execution times sorted by number of threads, instead of datasets. Such output is obtained executing this single awk script:

```
awk ' {if ($4 == "1") {print $3, $4, $6;}} ' kmeans_fastflow.log > t.dat
awk ' {if ($4 == "2") {print $3, $4, $6;}} ' kmeans_fastflow.log >> t.dat
awk ' {if ($4 == "3") {print $3, $4, $6;}} ' kmeans_fastflow.log >> t.dat
awk ' {if ($4 == "4") {print $3, $4, $6;}} ' kmeans_fastflow.log >> t.dat
awk ' {if ($4 == "5") {print $3, $4, $6;}} ' kmeans_fastflow.log >> t.dat
awk ' {if ($4 == "6") {print $3, $4, $6;}} ' kmeans_fastflow.log >> t.dat
awk ' {if ($4 == "7") {print $3, $4, $6;}} ' kmeans_fastflow.log >> t.dat
awk ' {if ($4 == "8") {print $3, $4, $6;}} ' kmeans_fastflow.log >> t.dat
awk ' {if ($4 == "9") {print $3, $4, $6;}} ' kmeans_fastflow.log >> t.dat
awk ' {if ($4 == "10") {print $3, $4, $6;}} ' kmeans_fastflow.log >> t.dat
awk ' {if ($4 == "11") {print $3, $4, $6;}} ' kmeans_fastflow.log >> t.dat
awk ' {if ($4 == "12") {print $3, $4, $6;}} ' kmeans_fastflow.log >> t.dat
```

Which gives the desired output:

```
number_of_threads: 1 8.001152
number_of_threads: 1 7.981428
number_of_threads: 1 7.986656
number_of_threads: 1 7.979782
number_of_threads: 1 7.980070
number_of_threads: 1 7.987722
number_of_threads: 1 7.980716
number_of_threads: 1 7.980209
number_of_threads: 1 7.982284
number_of_threads: 1 7.979446
number_of_threads: 1 56.425779
number_of_threads: 1 56.417835
number_of_threads: 1 56.426430
number_of_threads: 1 56.500974
number_of_threads: 1 56.447586
number_of_threads: 1 56.411380
number_of_threads: 1 56.453845
number_of_threads: 1 56.480448
number_of_threads: 1 56.442289
number_of_threads: 1 56.394068
number_of_threads: 1 89.251694
number_of_threads: 1 89.348788
number_of_threads: 1 89.281708
number_of_threads: 1 89.278013
number_of_threads: 1 89.299754
number_of_threads: 1 89.443212
number_of_threads: 1 89.300965
number_of_threads: 1 89.374555
number_of_threads: 1 89.307755
number_of_threads: 1 89.342808
number_of_threads: 2 4.003821
number_of_threads: 2 4.003638
number_of_threads: 2 4.003149
number_of_threads: 2 4.005415
number_of_threads: 2 4.003460
number_of_threads: 2 4.002836
number_of_threads: 2 4.005717
number_of_threads: 2 4.006178
number_of_threads: 2 4.004005
number_of_threads: 2 4.004230
number_of_threads: 2 28.258078
number_of_threads: 2 28.249284
number_of_threads: 2 28.264375
number_of_threads: 2 28.273207
number_of_threads: 2 28.228176
number_of_threads: 2 28.268416
number_of_threads: 2 28.240788
number_of_threads: 2 28.256000
number_of_threads: 2 28.262026
number_of_threads: 2 28.239830
number_of_threads: 2 44.681847
number_of_threads: 2 44.709311
number_of_threads: 2 44.668623
number_of_threads: 2 44.659865
number_of_threads: 2 44.699392
number_of_threads: 2 44.686959
number_of_threads: 2 44.671320
number_of_threads: 2 44.708551
number_of_threads: 2 44.731599
number_of_threads: 2 44.694352
.
.
.
number_of_threads: 12 0.679359
number_of_threads: 12 0.678121
number_of_threads: 12 0.680982
number_of_threads: 12 0.682098
number_of_threads: 12 0.679681
number_of_threads: 12 0.678525
number_of_threads: 12 0.679727
number_of_threads: 12 0.679983
number_of_threads: 12 0.678458
number_of_threads: 12 0.678074
number_of_threads: 12 4.772698
number_of_threads: 12 4.761998
number_of_threads: 12 4.743285
number_of_threads: 12 4.746927
number_of_threads: 12 4.746411
number_of_threads: 12 4.758229
number_of_threads: 12 4.772117
number_of_threads: 12 4.767569
number_of_threads: 12 4.759577
number_of_threads: 12 4.753897
number_of_threads: 12 7.533035
number_of_threads: 12 7.556848
number_of_threads: 12 7.558419
number_of_threads: 12 7.557569
number_of_threads: 12 7.533890
number_of_threads: 12 7.565937
number_of_threads: 12 7.579489
number_of_threads: 12 7.546736
number_of_threads: 12 7.539902
number_of_threads: 12 7.552226
```

How do I automatize this script so that it gives this desired output t.dat? (notice that it would be better if the results could be appended to the same file (using >>) after the first write (>)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to **sort**, use [`sort`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html). This sorts numerically based on the 4th column:

```
sort -n -k 4 file
```

Then, pipe to `awk` to get only some columns:

```
sort -n -k 4 file | awk '{print $3,$4,$6}'
```

Comment: It's a clever approach!